# How do you create a vertical stack org Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, orgchart

I need to build a Org Chart that prints from a web page and I have something like 19 to 32 entities on the second level and 3-7 entities on the third level.

I tried a solution called OrgChart component from Team Improver at
http://www.orgchartcomponent.com/default.aspx
but they are in England and don't respond to their email.

I also tried a solution from
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18378/Organization-Chart-Generator
that has the basic tree org chart.

I populate from a database via Ling to SQL, No Problem.

```
Parent Entity - Level 1
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
|
|
---Child Entity Level 2
          |
          |
          Child Entity Level 3
          |
          |
          Child Entity Level 3
          |
          |
          Child Entity Level 3
          |
          |
          Child Entity Level 3
```

Comment: Google charts has org chart you can use. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?csw=1

Comment: You can use GetOrgChart http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Orientation

Comment: I looking for a C# solution. Something I can set properties in c# or source code I can manipulate to create a vertical orientation. I have used Google Org Chart before. Not easy to manipulate and GetOrgChart is also not a c# solution.

Comment: @arraylist, hi, did you end up working this out? I’m trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Can say I ever did.

Comment: @Arraylist - What is your question here?

Answer (score 0):

```
// using recursive function.

    static void Get_Geneology(Employee manager, int Level = 0)  // find all genealogy (kid to great grandkids or employee under a manager down the pyramid)
    {
        string indentLines = new string(' ', Level * 2);
        var managedEmployees = Employees.Where(e => e.Manager_ID == manager.Emp_ID); // 1st call. look all employees under a Manager. or all kids of a father.
        Console.WriteLine($"{indentLines} {Level + 1}-{manager.FirstName}{(managedEmployees.Count() > 0 ? "*" : "")}"); // with * after name mean that person manage sombody or father have kid(s)

        foreach (var employee in managedEmployees) Get_Geneology(employee, Level + 1);   // recursive, find all under under (to the deapest of each people geneology for each manager)
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).